# Remote Desktop Services multiple display sizing issues

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop-services

A client of mine uses Remote Desktop Services publish through RemoteApp to individual workstations.

One of the users is complaining about an issue with a program that uses multiple windows. She runs Windows 10 Professional Fall Creators Update 2017. She has two monitors, one of which has a smaller resolution that the other.

Often times what happens when she resizes one of the windows, parts of the content, where the window edges would be, disappear. If she maximizes on the larger resolution monitor, the window pokes over into the smaller screen.

[Microsoft identified a problem with the Fall Creators version of mstsc.exe](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cdf12bbc-ff78-4d6e-9e12-63f99ae4d511/w10-1709-remoteapp-popups-hidden-behind-main-window?referrer=http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cdf12bbc-ff78-4d6e-9e12-63f99ae4d511/w10-1709-remoteapp-popups-hidden-behind-main-window?referrer=http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cdf12bbc-ff78-4d6e-9e12-63f99ae4d511/w10-1709-remoteapp-popups-hidden-behind-main-window?forum=winserverTS) and will issue a hotfix later this month. However, this problem pre-dates that update.

Is there a way to fix this so that the user can move between monitors and resize or maximize windows without these issues?

Comment: From the forum post you link, someone use mstsc.exe from an 1703 an it work, did you tried it ?

Comment: It’s an option, yes, but she had the problem when 1703 was the current version. To answer you specifically, no I haven’t tried it.

Comment: What happens if you reduce the resolution so both monitors are the same?

Comment: I have tried to do that. Each time, I would log the user out and back in but it hasn't fixed the issue.